# R how to read a .csv file with different separators

Tags: r, csv, separator

```
ItemID,Sentiment,SentimentSource,SentimentText

1,0,Sentiment140,     ok thats it you win.

2,0,Sentiment140,    i think mi bf is cheating on me!!!       T_T

3,0,Sentiment140,"    I'm completely useless rt now. Funny, all I can do is twitter. "
```

How would you read a csv file like this into R?

Comment: What's the issue here exactly? Looks completely comma-separated.

Comment: `read.csv` (`read.table`) has about the easiest to understand help of anything in the R help system. Read what the various arguments do.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've a big file with 4 fields and more than 800,000 tweets. At one point the read.csv command doesn't work as I would like (in Sentiment I find text) and I'm looking for the reason why this is happening. By the way, thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

Read a csv with `read.csv()`. You can specify `sep=""` to be whatever you need it to be. But as noted below, `,` is the default value for the separator.

[R: Data Input](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)

For example, csv file with comma as separator to a dataframe, manually choosing the file:

`df <- read.csv(file.choose())`

Comment: `header=TRUE, sep = ","` are the default for `read.csv` so they need not be specified.